# TLSv1.2 on tomcat jdbc connection

Tags: sql-server, java-8, tomcat9

My project setup uses mssql, tomcat9.0.59,java 1.8_322 and MSSql driver is mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre8.jar.

TLS 1.2 is enabled database server, after patching. Question is, How to configure jdbc connection properties to use TLSv1.2 protocol?

Tried using below configuration, but it is not working.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/connectionpool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="username" password="password"
          url="jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=testDb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          initialSize="5" maxWaitMillis="5000" maxTotal="600" maxIdle="50"
          validationQuery="select 1;" poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

below error is throwing while starting the tomcat.

```
13-May-2022 11:25:25.013 WARNING [main] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
    java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)". ClientConnectionId:e3c2518c-0eb4-4c1d-b223-7f2a1da3bd7a)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:653)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:532)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1057)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:308)
            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:399)
            at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:332)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
            at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? TLS 1.2 works in currently supported versions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [This Microsoft KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe) lists the older versions that need patching to support TLS 1.2. SQL Server 2016 and later don't need patching. The oldest version still in mainstream support is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Be aware that the client and server need to share not just a common TLS protocol version (e.g.: TLS 1.2) but also at least one common ciphersuite (e.g.: `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`). Decent server administrators will turn off the (weak) ciphersuites for the older TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 protocols when disabling them, but your JRE may only have those ciphersuites installed which would leave it unable to connect even though both sides declare support for TLS 1.2.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning TLS 1.0 is off by default on all *supported* drivers and operating systems by now and many have disabled TLS 1.1 as well. If the OP is using out-of-support versions, they'll need patching.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, SQL server version is 14.0.3281.6

Comment: That's SQL Server 2017 which *does* support TLS1.2. The JDBC driver does too. Try creating a new small console application that simply connects to the database, to ensure you *can* connect. Follow the steps in the [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/getting-started-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) driver docs and the [simplified example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-ver16). If that works, you'll know that your driver, DB and Java version are OK